# Crop uploaded photo before displaying in php

Tags: php, html

I'm new to ***php*** and I need help with the following problem. I want to add a script where I can crop and re-size my uploaded image to squares before displaying it. But I don't know how to do it because the photo will be ruined if I add something.

Here's the code:

**index.php**

```html
<html>
<head></head>

<body>

 <form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  FILE:
  <input type="file" name="image">
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">

 </form>

 <?php
 //connect to DB
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("company") or die(mysql_error());

 //file properties
 $file = &$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

 if(!isset($file))
  echo "Please select image";
 else
 {
  $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
  $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']); 
  $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
 
  if ($image_size==FALSE)
   echo "That's not an image.";
  else
  {
   if (!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO store VALUES ('','$image_name','$image')"))
    echo "Problem uploading...";
   else
   {
    $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
    echo "Image Uploaded <p> Your Image: </p> <img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";
  }
 }

 }
 ?>

</body>

</html>
```

**get.php**

```html
<?php 
    //connect to DB
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("company") or die(mysql_error());

    $id = addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);

    $image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store WHERE id=$id");
    $image = mysql_fetch_array($image);
    $image =$image['image'];

    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

    echo $image;

?>
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried Crop and Resize Images with ImageMagick? 
http://www.sitepoint.com/crop-and-resize-images-with-imagemagick/

```
<?php
    $inFile = "test.jpg";
    $outFile = "test-cropped.jpg";
    $image = new Imagick($inFile);
    $image->cropImage(400,400, 30,10);
    $image->writeImage($outFile);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have any kind of uploading system for images, you can use [wideimage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/) to crop a picture so you have two versions one small and the original.